# Does the color red make you hungrier?

Tags: psychology, consciousness, colors

I'll quote [something](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Does_colors_make_you_hungry) I found by googling *[red hungry](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=red%20hungry)*:

> A variety of colors can trigger hunger. The most influential colors in terms of food are: red, orange, yellow. [...]
>
> A color psychologist would tell you that this is no surprise: red is the color that makes people hungry. Red instantly attracts attention and it also makes people excited, energetic, and increases the heart rate.

I've heard this a lot, but I have never noticed it working on myself.  If it does work, it would have to be a subconscious process.  Has anyone ever verified this?

Edit: The claims I have heard and can see out there usually have to do with the advertising and decor surrounding food, as in [this article](http://www.famouslogos.org/the-psychology-of-fast-food-logos), which I found in [this UX.SE answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/14242) to the question [Which colors make you hungry](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/14239).

Also, in my above quote, color psychology is mentioned. Are there research papers not only hypothesizing associations between color and behavior, but demonstrating experimental data? In the [Color Psychology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_psychology) wikipedia page, many references to research papers are made, but many of them (the ones I clicked to and read the abstracts of) don't describe empirical proof, sometimes instead using such associations as a given and a platform on which other theories are established (I don't want to pay $35.95 to be sure though).

Comment: Why on earth would you Google *red hungry*, of all things?

Comment: No wonder I get the urge to snack while sitting at traffic lights...

Comment: I do not quite understand what u are trying to ask, are u looking for sources, or whether the claim that red triggers hunger is true and authentic or what?

Comment: I'm asking whether the claim is true; naturally sources would help :)

Comment: @user4882: I googled keywords to find whether the claim I'd heard was documented enough to be viable.

Answer (score 7):

This is indeed an interesting question so I'll attempt to answer it.

Many articles posted on the internet **claim** that the color red makes you hungry, and they claim that junk food giants (like KFC) use this color in their logos, those articles include: [Examiner.com](http://www.examiner.com/article/red-color-stimulates-appetite), [Ask.com](http://www.ask.com/science/red-yellow-make-hungry-185c9f22bb9bc92f#full-answer), [Huffingtonpost.ca](http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/2013/04/03/hunger-causes-walls_n_3007712.html),  [Azscience.org](http://azscience.org/never_stop_wondering/video/why_do_the_colors_red_and_yellow_make_you_hungry), [Dailyinfographic.org](http://dailyinfographic.com/the-psychology-of-colors-infographic), [wikispaces.com](http://nrlbeiser.wikispaces.com/Restaurant+music,+color,+and+decor?responseToken=0b290fbd500e3c17c20b8c91e832073e5), [rustrybee.com](http://rustybee.com/why-red-and-yellow-are-so-popular-for-kitchen-colors/), [omgfacts.com](http://www.omgfacts.com/lists/4532/The-color-red-is-scientifically-proven-to-make-you-hungry) and sometimes they announce extraordinary unferenced claims like this one on [thegloss.com](http://www.thegloss.com/2011/03/28/fashion/why-red-makes-you-hungry-other-things-you-didnt-know-about-color/):

> It has to do with the way it affects your brain. **Red releases
>   endorphins into your system that stimulate the appetite.**

Most of them give reference to this article (who apparently is offline now):

http://www.colorschemer.com/blog/2007/07/17/why-food-companies-use-red-colors/

Fortunately, I could get a version from Wayback Machine, you can see it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130215112529/http://www.colorschemer.com/blog/2007/07/17/why-food-companies-use-red-colors).

The article is small, unreferenced and full of logical falacies.

For example, they say that:

> What do Safeway, Walgreens, and Costco have in common? The obvious
>   answer is that they are all large operated American supermarkets. But
>   do you think it’s any coincidence that these three grocery stores –
>   along with others like Winn-Dixie, Wawa, Giant, and Supervalu – all
>   use red in their logo?

Interesting, they mention a list of junk-food restaurants (or supermarkets) who list red in their logo as a proof that they Red makes you hungry.

They also forget to mention restaurants that don't use red in their logos, like:

- Subway
- Taco Bell
- Dunkin Donuts
- Applebee's
- On the border
- Shake snack
- Just salad
- White Castle
- Panera
- Starbucks
- Little Caesars
- Carvel
- The list goes on...

*If you google any name from the list, you would see that the logo doesn't have a red colour.*

[With the help of Rob Marsh](http://www.logomaker.com/blog/2014/10/15/color-red-wont-make-hungry-unless-youre-fish/), I found an interesting [academic article](http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0059134&representation=PDF) called "Impact of color on marketing". They found out that:

> red light stimulates feeding, as in humans, most likely by affecting
>   central control centers, but the extra feeding is not converted into
>   growth.

This study proves that red stimulates hunger in fish, and also claim that it stimulates hunger in humans by referencing to:

> **Satyendra Singh, (2006) "Impact of color on marketing", Management
>   Decision, Vol. 44 Iss: 6, pp.783 - 789**

If you dig in Singh's [article](http://personal.stevens.edu/~rchen/creativity/impact%20of%20color%20on%20marketing.pdf):

> The red color stimulates appetite because of its effect on our
>   metabolism, making red a popular color choice among fast-food
>   restaurants.... This is an important strategy for formal restaurants to increase their sales

you would notice bizarre thing about this paper is that this claim is unreferenced.

Finally, I found a referenced academic article by Appetite which actually say the opposite:

**[The color red reduces snack food and soft drink intake](https://moodle.zhaw.ch/pluginfile.php/404472/mod_resource/content/0/R/GIS_0047_Genschow_2012.pdf)**

From Abstract:

> Based on evidence that the color red elicits avoidance motivation
>   across contexts (Mehta & Zhu, 2009), two studies investigated the
>   effect of the color red on snack food and soft drink consumption. In
>   line with our hypothesis, participants drank less from a red labeled
>   cup than from a blue labeled cup (Study 1), and ate less snack food
>   from a red plate than from a blue or white plate (Study 2). The
>   results suggest that red functions as a subtle stop signal that works
>   outside of focused awareness and thereby reduces incidental food and
>   drink intake.

Enough said. You may look into the studies, they seem convincing.

So, answering your question:

> Does the color red make you hungrier?

Not according to scientific evidence. [Rob Marsh](https://plus.google.com/118286264686230590440?rel=author), an entrepreneur and expert with logos had an interesting [opinion](http://www.logomaker.com/blog/2014/10/15/color-red-wont-make-hungry-unless-youre-fish/):

> If you’ve had a positive experience with these brands, they may
>   trigger an “I’d love a blizzard and fries right about now” kind of
>   response. But it has very little to do with the color red.
>
> Color meaning is situational.
>
> Seeing a brand new red restaurant logo isn’t likely to make you hungry
>   (at least until you connect it to a positive eating experience). And
>   it probably won’t raise your heart rate. But it might catch your
>   attention—especially if the red stands out from the surrounding
>   environment. That’s what red does best.
>
> So you can probably forget those color psychology posters and
>   recommendations. Including ours. When it comes to color, a lot of
>   what’s said is conjecture or just plain wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not colour blind,. but I see a lot of red among those logos you claim don't have red in them. McDonalds may have the golden arches but next time you see the sign you'll notice a great deal of red. Also Outback, Chilis, DQ, IHOP, Applebees.....

Comment: Glad you found our research helpful (referenced in your answer). I spent several days pouring over research papers and the only claim I could find that the color red could stimulate appetite was the study on fish mentioned above. It's quite a leap to apply that to humans. Lots of people claim red makes you hungry (or repeat the claims) despite the fact that the science to prove it hasn't been done. If the science is out there, I was unable to find it. -rm

Comment: I awarded you the bounty - thanks for answering! But I'm not yet satisfied that any of the studies you reference accurately ascertain whether or in what cases environmental color has an effect on human appetite, so I'm leaving it unaccepted still.